# How do I bring an array up a level?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array like

```
$array ( 
     [1]( [camera_name] = name1 )
     [2]( [camera_name] = name2 )
     [3]( [camera_name] = name3 )
     [4]( [camera_name] = name4 )
)
```

and I just want it so that it is

```
Array (
    [1] = name1,
    [2] = name2,
    [3] = name3,
    [4] = name4 )
```

I've tried

```
for($i;$i<count($array);$i++){
     $newArray = $array[$i][camera_name];
}
```

also

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
     $newArray[$key] = $array[$key][camera_name];
}
```

But no matter what I do the array always ends up the same:

```
$newArray ( 
     [1]( [camera_name] = name1 )
     [2]( [camera_name] = name2 )
     [3]( [camera_name] = name3 )
     [4]( [camera_name] = name4 )
)
```

Comment: That second piece of code should actually work. Also: [Why is `$foo[bar]` wrong?](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do following code :

```
$array    = array( /* added data */ );// your original array
$tempArray = array();

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  $tempArray[$key] = $value['camera_name'];
}

print_r($tempArray);
```

Not the output will be

```
$newArray ( 
     [1]( [camera_name] = name1 )
     [2]( [camera_name] = name2 )
     [3]( [camera_name] = name3 )
     [4]( [camera_name] = name4 )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array_map(function (array $item) { return $item['camera_name']; }, $array);
```

As of PHP 5.5:

```
$array = array_column($array, 'camera_name');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
$newArray = array();
$i =1;
foreach($array as $key => $value){
     $newArray[$i] = $value;
     $i++;
}


print_r($newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong

Should be like this:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    $newArray[$key] = $value['camera_man']; // $value['camera_man']
}
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [1] => name1
    [2] => name2
    [3] => name3
    [4] => name4
)
```